# Latex's rendering feature --- I guess!

Tags: fonts, layout

How I can rendering text in latex document to look bright and crystal clear such as the one on the following link:
https://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/extract/extract.pdf

Comment: Did you try looking at the source code for the manual?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What exactly to you mean with "bright and crystal clear"? Could you please provide an example how text rendered with LaTeX differs from what you expect?

Comment: I actually I am new to latex. I can't understand much of latex code I- I can not understand the feature very well.

Comment: This is fine, but please help us understand what you want to achieve. Dou you mean a certain font in this file? Or maybe the colored vertical text on the first side? Or do you want to copy the whole layout from this file?

Comment: I meant the font ; it resolution is high - what I am looking for?

Comment: by default your latex installation should be using scalable fonts so they have no "resolution". If you are using the default computer modern with miktex make sure you have cm-super installed.  (or add `\usepackage{lmodern}`)

Comment: Hello @ahmedmokhtar. Please add a MWE (minimal working example) or a MnWE (non-working). 
Over all, it is better to see, where you want to use it and help there. We don't know, how exactly the author did this and it is very often not a fast solution to try to find out, how the author did it. 
Over all, personally I think, that this isn't good style. So, if you show us, where you want to use it, we might also be able to give a better stylistic solution.

Comment: If you are having a hard time getting into LaTeX, consider checking out my easy LaTeX introduction on github. It is a letter template, but you can reuse it right away: https://github.com/MaestroGlanz/Easy_LaTeX_Introduction